# cannot solve my flask bluprint assertion error

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to split my app with using Bluprint in flask, but i got AssertionError though there's no funtions having same names. i thought if the function name is different, the default endpoint will be different too. I've searched for it, but still i couldent get so far. please help ;(

this is my controllers.py

```
import flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, make_response, g, session, jsonify
from apps import app, db
from apps.models import *

from apps.controllers2 import app2

#Set application.debug=true to enable tracebacks on Beanstalk log output.
#Make sure to remove this line before deploying to production.
app.debug=True
app.register_blueprint(app2)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/intro', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hmp_showIntro():
    return render_template('intro.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

and this is separated controller, controller2.py

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, make_response, g, session, jsonify
from flask import Blueprint
from apps import app, db
app2 = Blueprint('app2', __name__)

@app2.route('/main')
def hmp_showMain():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

and here is what i've got

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=15429): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/apps/controllers.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/python/current/app/apps/controllers.py", line 17, in <module>
     @app.route('/intro', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1013, in decorator
     self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 984, in add_url_rule
     'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
 AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: hmp_showIntro
```

Comment: Functions like `url_for` use the names of your view functions to resolve urls. That is why there can be no two view functions with the same name `hmp_showIntro`. It doesn't matter that they are in separate blueprints, as blueprints simply deffer the registration of a view until you call `app.register_blueprint` so that is basically identical to registering the function with the same name twice on the main app object. You can probably avoid that by using [`endpoint` parameter of `route` decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.route).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app already has route to view with `hmp_showIntro` name. Search project for that function. Or you can do double import of controllers.py.

Comment: thanks. i couldn't find where the double import occered, but the issue solved